# how to check session in ajax

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

i want to chek is the user is loggedin before hitting the ajax request
or i want to chek in ajax handler(ashx file)

i have httpContext there in ashx file 
can i chek thru dis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`IHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) (.ashx handler) handler make it implement the [`IReadOnlySessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.ireadonlysessionstate(v=VS.100).aspx) or [`IRequiresSessionState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.irequiressessionstate(v=VS.100).aspx) (if it needs to set anything) interfaces, like this:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
  {
    //You can use session here
  }
  public bool IsReusable { get { return true; } } //this may vary for you
}
```

Comment: i have dis code

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
  {
    //You can use session here
  }


but how to use context to chek if the user is logged in

Comment: @vakas - That depends what login provider you're using, Forms, something else?  It's the same way you'd check in any other page in your application, e.g. `if(Session["LoggedIn"] != null)` as a simple (though bad!) example, or say if you're storing a user object, `Session["user"] != null`....whatever your check is.